# Replace emails using gsub

Tags: regex, r

How can I replace an email `regex` pattern to missing. I have tried

```
blogs.smpl <- "mami@yahoo.com : subject:Lorem Ipsum body:   is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem@Ipsum.com has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"
blogs.smpl1 <- gsub("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+$","",blogs.smpl )
blogs.smpl1
```

But doesn't replace the email addresses. I have also tried using this pattern
 `email2 <- "^[[:alnum:].-]+@[[:alnum:].-]+$"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**anchors**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html) around your entire pattern are the problem. The `^` anchor asserts that the regex engine's current position in the string is the beginning of the string and `$` asserts the position at the end of the string. These addresses are at neither position in your string. So, by implementing both anchors, you're telling the engine your entire string should match this pattern.

You could simply remove both of the anchors and it would replace the addresses in your data. Alternatively, if you know these addresses are always bounded by whitespace, this would suffice.

```
gsub('\\S+@\\S+', '', blogs.smpl)
```